# How to add additional value into an existing key in Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap containing these following values:

```
HashMap<String, JSONObject> myMap = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
JSONObject name1 = new JSONObject();
name1.put("name", "A");
..... //so on for name2 and name3

myMap.put("1", name1);
myMap.put("2", name2);
myMap.put("3", name3);
System.out.println(myMap.get("1");

Output is {"name", "A"}.
```

How can I insert additional value to one of the existing key so the output should be like this:

```
System.out.println(myMap.get("1");

=> Expected output is {{"name", "A"}, {"age", "30"}}
```

Comment: Do a `map.get` grab the object, modify it, then `put` it back into the map.

Comment: @alfasin, you don't need to do a `put` if the instance isn't being replaced. However, if for example the Map's value type is String, the new String instance would need to be `put` to overwrite existing value.

Comment: does the java compiler accept this syntax `myMap.put("1",{Personal:[{"name":"A"}]});` ?

Comment: I have updated the code to be more clear.  But the same question remains on how I can update the value and not override the existing value?

Comment: json object format you specify is not correct {{"name", "A"}, {"age", "30"}} it should be  [{"name":"A"}, {"age": "30"}] or  { "name": "A" :  "age"  "30" }, what do you exactly need?

Answer (score 1):

You can do both:

A) Create a normal `HashMap` where the value type is a container (e.g. `List`);

```
HashMap<String, List<Object>> myMultiMap = new HashMap<>();
// Add a list with the objects you want
myMultiMap.put("name", [a list with elements])
// You can use the .compute method to add elements to existing lists
```

or

B) Create a Multi-Valued Map, which is not provided by default by the JDK, but can be found in libraries like [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) or [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but in my scenario, the additional element is added based on a condition.  If I create a HashMap with List<Object>, does it require that I need to have a list of elements?

Comment: Yes, you will have to create and manage the list. With that control, you can check the conditions however you want.

If you want a key in a map to have multiple values, you need to have a collection somehow.  That will be either controlled by you or by a library.